# How to update UI using inertiajs?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I am working on a project developed with react laravel and inertiajs. It's the first project of this kind and I don't know how I can update the UI after I change something. Normally, if I were to develop this project using only react, I would use react-query which would make my job much easier, but in this project I cannot use this approach. Please, who knows, explain to me how I can update the UI in this situation. Is there a function to mutate props?
Thank you!